# SQL query using Snowflake syntax

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I am trying to get the the data that occurs as events in a fact table to be pivoted and captured in a clean format as below, any suggestions as to how this can be accomplished using SQL syntax that is compatible with snowflake ?

The events are expected to appear in below format:

1.subscription_id
2.cancel
3.survey

I need to capture the first occurrence of cancel & survey that appears right below subscription_id. There can be cases where subscription_id occurs but there can be no immediate 'cancel' or 'survey'. So in that case we need to ignore 'cancel' or survey page_name

There can also be cases where we can have multiple 'cancel' or 'survey' in that case we need to capture the first occurrence after subscription_id

Input Table format:

| Session | page_name | page_value | page_num | Timestamp |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | subscription_id | 12345 | 5 | 1/1/20 13:00 |
| 1 | cancel | no_interest | 6 | 1/1/20 13:05 |
| 1 | cancel | watch_all | 7 | 1/1/20 13:10 |
| 1 | Survey | Clicked | 8 | 1/1/20 13:15 |
| 1 | Survey | Not_clicked | 9 | 1/1/20 13:20 |
| 1 | subscription_id | 456 | 10 | 1/1/20 13:25 |
| 1 | cancel | don’t_like | 11 | 1/1/20 13:30 |
| 1 | cancel | bored | 12 | 1/1/20 13:40 |
| 1 | subscription_id | 789 | 13 | 1/1/20 13:45 |
| 1 | Survey | Not_clicked | 14 | 1/1/20 13:50 |
| 1 | cancel | watch_all | 15 | 1/1/20 13:55 |
| 1 | Survey | Clicked | 16 | 1/1/20 14:15 |

Expected Table format:

| Session | subscription_id | cancel_reason | Cancel_time | Survey_reason | Survey_time |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 12345 | no_interest | 1/1/20 13:05 | Clicked | 1/1/20 13:15 |
| 1 | 456 | don’t_lke | 1/1/20 13:30 |  |  |
| 1 | 789 |  |  | Not_clicked | 1/1/20 13:50 |

Comment: Avoid uploading images https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors-when-asking-a-question

Comment: there seems to be no details relating the three streams of values. Is the assumption that all rows between `subscription_id`'s are bound to that row?

Comment: Session_id bounds all rows together

Comment: Why doesn't survey 789 have cancel_reason = watch_all?

Comment: that's because it appears after survey

Comment: ah, for those rules you might need to use https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/constructs/match_recognize.html, or wait for someone to hand roll the rule.

Comment: @SimeonPilgrim Or, just one final outer query with `iff(cancel_timestamp < survey_timestamp, cancel_xxx, null)`

Comment: @MatBailie that would seem to work also..

Comment: @MatBailie I now added how I read you suggestion for your FIRST_VALUE style solution.

Answer (score 1):

So the first part of the problem is to give each thing a grouping cluster, which can be done with [CONDITIONAL_TRUE_EVENT](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions/conditional_true_event.html)

```
with data(page_name, page_value, page_num, timestamp) as (
    select * from values
        ('subscription_id', '12345', 5, '2020-01-01 13:00'::timestamp),
        ('cancel', 'no_interest', 6, '2020-01-01 13:05'::timestamp),
        ('cancel', 'watch_all', 7, '2020-01-01 13:10'::timestamp),
        ('Survey', 'Clicked', 8, '2020-01-01 13:15'::timestamp),
        ('Survey', 'Not_clicked', 9, '2020-01-01 13:20'::timestamp),
        ('subscription_id', '456', 10, '2020-01-01 13:25'::timestamp),
        ('cancel', 'don''t_like', 11, '2020-01-01 13:30'::timestamp),
        ('cancel', 'bored', 12, '2020-01-01 13:40'::timestamp),
        ('subscription_id', '789', 13, '2020-01-01 13:45'::timestamp),
        ('Survey', 'Not_clicked', 14, '2020-01-01 13:50'::timestamp),
        ('cancel', 'watch_all', 15, '2020-01-01 13:55'::timestamp),
        ('Survey', 'Clicked', 16, '2020-01-01 14:15'::timestamp)
)
select *
    ,CONDITIONAL_TRUE_EVENT(page_name='subscription_id')over(order by page_num) as event_grp
from data
```

| PAGE_NAME | PAGE_VALUE | PAGE_NUM | TIMESTAMP | EVENT_GRP |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| subscription_id | 12345 | 5 | 2020-01-01 13:00:00.000 | 1 |
| cancel | no_interest | 6 | 2020-01-01 13:05:00.000 | 1 |
| cancel | watch_all | 7 | 2020-01-01 13:10:00.000 | 1 |
| Survey | Clicked | 8 | 2020-01-01 13:15:00.000 | 1 |
| Survey | Not_clicked | 9 | 2020-01-01 13:20:00.000 | 1 |
| subscription_id | 456 | 10 | 2020-01-01 13:25:00.000 | 2 |
| cancel | don't_like | 11 | 2020-01-01 13:30:00.000 | 2 |
| cancel | bored | 12 | 2020-01-01 13:40:00.000 | 2 |
| subscription_id | 789 | 13 | 2020-01-01 13:45:00.000 | 3 |
| Survey | Not_clicked | 14 | 2020-01-01 13:50:00.000 | 3 |
| cancel | watch_all | 15 | 2020-01-01 13:55:00.000 | 3 |
| Survey | Clicked | 16 | 2020-01-01 14:15:00.000 | 3 |

Then using [QUALIFY](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/constructs/qualify.html)/[ROW_NUMBER](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions/row_number.html) on that we can keep the first of each groups... but qualify cannot we used in the same block as a CONDITIONAL_TRUE_EVENT.. so nested it is:

```
select * from (
    select *
        ,CONDITIONAL_TRUE_EVENT(page_name='subscription_id')over(order by page_num) as event_grp
    from data
) 
qualify row_number()over(partition by event_grp, page_name order by timestamp) = 1
```

| PAGE_NAME | PAGE_VALUE | PAGE_NUM | TIMESTAMP | EVENT_GRP |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| subscription_id | 12345 | 5 | 2020-01-01 13:00:00.000 | 1 |
| cancel | no_interest | 6 | 2020-01-01 13:05:00.000 | 1 |
| Survey | Clicked | 8 | 2020-01-01 13:15:00.000 | 1 |
| subscription_id | 456 | 10 | 2020-01-01 13:25:00.000 | 2 |
| cancel | don't_like | 11 | 2020-01-01 13:30:00.000 | 2 |
| subscription_id | 789 | 13 | 2020-01-01 13:45:00.000 | 3 |
| Survey | Not_clicked | 14 | 2020-01-01 13:50:00.000 | 3 |
| cancel | watch_all | 15 | 2020-01-01 13:55:00.000 | 3 |

Now to do the ORDER of event filter:

```
with data(session, page_name, page_value, page_num, timestamp) as (
    select * from values
        (1,'subscription_id', '12345', 5, '2020-01-01 13:00'::timestamp),
        (1,'cancel', 'no_interest', 6, '2020-01-01 13:05'::timestamp),
        (1,'cancel', 'watch_all', 7, '2020-01-01 13:10'::timestamp),
        (1,'Survey', 'Clicked', 8, '2020-01-01 13:15'::timestamp),
        (1,'Survey', 'Not_clicked', 9, '2020-01-01 13:20'::timestamp),
        (1,'subscription_id', '456', 10, '2020-01-01 13:25'::timestamp),
        (1,'cancel', 'don''t_like', 11, '2020-01-01 13:30'::timestamp),
        (1,'cancel', 'bored', 12, '2020-01-01 13:40'::timestamp),
        (1,'subscription_id', '789', 13, '2020-01-01 13:45'::timestamp),
        (1,'Survey', 'Not_clicked', 14, '2020-01-01 13:50'::timestamp),
        (1,'cancel', 'watch_all', 15, '2020-01-01 13:55'::timestamp),
        (1,'Survey', 'Clicked', 16, '2020-01-01 14:15'::timestamp)
), step_one as (
    select * from (
        select *
          ,CONDITIONAL_TRUE_EVENT(page_name='subscription_id')over(partition by session order by page_num) as event_grp
        from data
    )
    qualify row_number()over(partition by session, event_grp, page_name order by timestamp) = 1
    
)--, step_two as (
    select *
        ,row_number()over(partition by session, event_grp order by timestamp) as rn
    from step_one
    qualify case 
        when page_name='subscription_id' then true
        when page_name='cancel' and rn = 2 then true
        when page_name='Survey' then true
        else false end  
;)
```

gives:

| SESSION | PAGE_NAME | PAGE_VALUE | PAGE_NUM | TIMESTAMP | EVENT_GRP | RN |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | subscription_id | 12345 | 5 | 2020-01-01 13:00:00.000 | 1 | 1 |
| 1 | cancel | no_interest | 6 | 2020-01-01 13:05:00.000 | 1 | 2 |
| 1 | Survey | Clicked | 8 | 2020-01-01 13:15:00.000 | 1 | 3 |
| 1 | subscription_id | 456 | 10 | 2020-01-01 13:25:00.000 | 2 | 1 |
| 1 | cancel | don't_like | 11 | 2020-01-01 13:30:00.000 | 2 | 2 |
| 1 | subscription_id | 789 | 13 | 2020-01-01 13:45:00.000 | 3 | 1 |
| 1 | Survey | Not_clicked | 14 | 2020-01-01 13:50:00.000 | 3 | 2 |

so now we can unpivot this with [MAX](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions/min.html) and [IFF](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions/iff.html), The iff is used to select the only value we want, and the MAX take the non-null value (which due to the ROW_NUMBER fitlering of the prior step there is only one non-null value per column)

```
with data(session, page_name, page_value, page_num, timestamp) as (
    select * from values
        (1,'subscription_id', '12345', 5, '2020-01-01 13:00'::timestamp),
        (1,'cancel', 'no_interest', 6, '2020-01-01 13:05'::timestamp),
        (1,'cancel', 'watch_all', 7, '2020-01-01 13:10'::timestamp),
        (1,'Survey', 'Clicked', 8, '2020-01-01 13:15'::timestamp),
        (1,'Survey', 'Not_clicked', 9, '2020-01-01 13:20'::timestamp),
        (1,'subscription_id', '456', 10, '2020-01-01 13:25'::timestamp),
        (1,'cancel', 'don''t_like', 11, '2020-01-01 13:30'::timestamp),
        (1,'cancel', 'bored', 12, '2020-01-01 13:40'::timestamp),
        (1,'subscription_id', '789', 13, '2020-01-01 13:45'::timestamp),
        (1,'Survey', 'Not_clicked', 14, '2020-01-01 13:50'::timestamp),
        (1,'cancel', 'watch_all', 15, '2020-01-01 13:55'::timestamp),
        (1,'Survey', 'Clicked', 16, '2020-01-01 14:15'::timestamp)
), step_one as (
    select * from (
        select *
          ,CONDITIONAL_TRUE_EVENT(page_name='subscription_id')over(partition by session order by page_num) as event_grp
        from data
    )
    qualify row_number()over(partition by session, event_grp, page_name order by timestamp) = 1
    
), step_two as (
    select *
        ,row_number()over(partition by session, event_grp order by timestamp) as rn
    from step_one
    qualify case 
        when page_name='subscription_id' then true
        when page_name='cancel' and rn = 2 then true
        when page_name='Survey' then true
        else false end  
)
select 
    session
    ,max(iff(page_name='subscription_id',page_value, null)) as subscription_id
    ,max(iff(page_name='cancel',page_value, null)) as cancel_reason
    ,max(iff(page_name='cancel',timestamp, null)) as cancel_timestamp
    ,max(iff(page_name='Survey',page_value, null)) as Survey_reason
    ,max(iff(page_name='Survey',timestamp, null)) as Survey_timestamp
from step_two
group by session, event_grp
order by session, event_grp
```

gives:

| SESSION | SUBSCRIPTION_ID | CANCEL_REASON | CANCEL_TIMESTAMP | SURVEY_REASON | SURVEY_TIMESTAMP |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 12345 | no_interest | 2020-01-01 13:05:00.000 | Clicked | 2020-01-01 13:15:00.000 |
| 1 | 456 | don't_like | 2020-01-01 13:30:00.000 | null | null |
| 1 | 789 | null | null | Not_clicked | 2020-01-01 13:50:00.000 |

### the Mat Solution:

Not how I would solve this:

```
with data(session, page_name, page_value, page_num, timestamp) as (
    select * from values
        (1,'subscription_id', '12345', 5, '2020-01-01 13:00'::timestamp),
        (1,'cancel', 'no_interest', 6, '2020-01-01 13:05'::timestamp),
        (1,'cancel', 'watch_all', 7, '2020-01-01 13:10'::timestamp),
        (1,'Survey', 'Clicked', 8, '2020-01-01 13:15'::timestamp),
        (1,'Survey', 'Not_clicked', 9, '2020-01-01 13:20'::timestamp),
        (1,'subscription_id', '456', 10, '2020-01-01 13:25'::timestamp),
        (1,'cancel', 'don''t_like', 11, '2020-01-01 13:30'::timestamp),
        (1,'cancel', 'bored', 12, '2020-01-01 13:40'::timestamp),
        (1,'subscription_id', '789', 13, '2020-01-01 13:45'::timestamp),
        (1,'Survey', 'Not_clicked', 14, '2020-01-01 13:50'::timestamp),
        (1,'cancel', 'watch_all', 15, '2020-01-01 13:55'::timestamp),
        (1,'Survey', 'Clicked', 16, '2020-01-01 14:15'::timestamp)
), step_one as (
    select *
      ,CONDITIONAL_TRUE_EVENT(page_name='subscription_id')over(partition by session order by page_num) as event_grp
    from data
)
select 
    session,
    iff(Survey_timestamp is null OR cancel_timestamp<Survey_timestamp, cancel_reason, null) as cancel_reason,
    iff(Survey_timestamp is null OR cancel_timestamp<Survey_timestamp, cancel_timestamp, null) as cancel_timestamp,
    Survey_reason,
    Survey_timestamp
from (
    select distinct
        session, event_grp
        ,first_value(iff(page_name='subscription_id',page_value, null))ignore nulls over(partition by session, event_grp order by timestamp) as subscription_id
        ,first_value(iff(page_name='cancel',page_value, null))ignore nulls over(partition by session, event_grp order by timestamp) as cancel_reason
        ,first_value(iff(page_name='cancel',timestamp, null))ignore nulls over(partition by session, event_grp order by timestamp) as cancel_timestamp
        ,first_value(iff(page_name='Survey',page_value, null))ignore nulls over(partition by session, event_grp order by timestamp) as Survey_reason
        ,first_value(iff(page_name='Survey',timestamp, null))ignore nulls over(partition by session, event_grp order by timestamp) as Survey_timestamp
    from step_one
)
order by session, event_grp
```

Comment: Very very nice answer indeed (wish I could up vote twice). Good spot on the IS NULL condition at the end. Having realised that I'd reverse the logic; `iff(x > y, NULL, cancel_xxx)`. The reversed logic can also shorten the QUALIFY CASE expression, if so desired.

Comment: Oh I like that suggestion.